# How to delete a fleet that is still missing in action in Stellaris

Tags: stellaris

I've encountered a bug - after assimilating a vassal empire, the vassal's fleet joins my own. Part of that vassal fleet happened to be in another empire's territory at the time, resulting in an MIA scenario. Unlike a regular post-war MIA scenario, however, the date of return changes synchronously with the game date timer, resulting in an MIA fleet that will never return. For example, on a certain date, the date of return is 15th Nov 2306, and half a month later, it becomes 30th Nov 2306, and so on. This is very annoying, as it severely limits the size of my fleet. Is there a way by which I can delete the missing fleet?